# AC Ultrasonic Speaker Design

Tags: signal, speakers, ultrasound, conversion

As a software engineer I apologize in advance, I'm definitely an amateur in the field of electronics.

**Problem**

I'm looking to gauge distance from an ultrasonic emitter to a mobile device. To test this idea, I've built a proof-of-concept app that takes microphone input, runs it through a Fast Fourier Transform, and using the [inverse square law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Acoustic/invsqs.html) of the frequencies' amplitude to guage distance

Now I'm looking to build a reproducible speaker (that is, not my laptop's) that has high output (dbA) at ultrasonic frequencies (20khz-22khz). **note**: the frequency can be constant if it makes things easier to build.

**Where I'm At**

To start I looked up speakers that were designed to produce ultrasonic frequency,  I've found [this speaker](http://www.brocott.co.uk/mini-piezoelectric-tweeter/) which generates frequencies from 2.1khz-45khz at 118dB (which seems significant)

```
Rat. Impedance: <1200 Ohm
Rat. Noise Voltage: 14V
Crossover Fraq. Range (fc): 10000 +_ 25% Hz
Rat. Fraq. Range: 2500 - 45000 Hz
Sound Pressure Level: max. 118dB +_15%
```

Reading the specifications I see the rated voltage is 14v. So knowing I'm probably going to need to want the final current to be an AC, I looked up 120V to 14V, AC to AC transformers. These seem pretty easy to find. I found [this](http://www.jameco.com/z/ACU140085H5780-AC-to-AC-Wall-Adapter-Transformer-14-Volt-850mA-Black-Right-angle-2-5mm-Female-Plug_318684.html).

```
Input Voltage: 120VAC @ 60Hz
Output Rating: 14VAC @ 850mA
Size: 2.5"H x 2.0"W x 1.7"D
```

Now here is where I'm stuck. I have the desired 14V output, but the current as far as I know is still alternating  60HZ (standard American wall-out).

I'm unaware of any off the shelf methods to convert a 60HZ AC current to the static 20khz-22khz signal that I need. Is there an easy/cheap way? What parts should I be looking at? It seems that any signal generators that I find are super expensive and very general-purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: As you sound more than fluent in code, setting up a PWM output on an ardunio should be fairly easy to do, boost the power output with a gate driver.

Comment: I second this. Arduino [+ audio amplifier] + ultrasonic transducer will produce your desired transmitter. By the way, for the receiver you don't need an fft, just an fir filter to isolate the required frequencies. Last comment: you need to modulate the ultrasound, perhaps turn it on and off 55 times per second, so your app can be sure it's seeing a beacon, not just a source of general noise like a fan. You could of course encode the beacon's ID into the sound, etc.

Comment: @tomnexus have any documentation of someone using a fir filter to isolate a frequency? I ran into the Goertzel Filter a while back, just had problems finding a good implementation of it. Is that similar to what your talking about?

Comment: Nothing specific, but it's what I have used. Search for any online filter designer, perhaps use a Chebyshev filter. Don't be too greedy about the stop bands, find a reasonable order filter to isolate say 21+-1 kHz. Then find the total power in the filtered time series by squaring and summing a bunch of samples. How many depends on how fast you want it to respond. Eg: 44kHz sampling, 100 taps will get you 2 kHz or so. Sum of 2000 samples (squared) is the power for that 50 ms. I read about the Goertzel Filter, interesting, could also work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an XY problem.  While a piezo disk, tweater, or even a general purpose speaker will produce substantial energy at ~20 KHz which the MEMs microphones in most phones will pick up easily, the described amplitude-based distancing scheme will not be practical.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the signal using your PC or whatever microprocessor you are using for the FFT.

You don't want a transformer.

You want an amplifier.  You will have to find (or build) one intended to operate at the proper frequency range.

---

You don't want to try to do range finding using the inverse square law.  The results will be very inconsistent.

There are complete modules that do ultrasonic ranging.  They measure the time it takes for the echo to return.

They send a pulse of ultrasound, and measure the time until the echo is received. Since the speed of sound in air is fairly constant in normal temperatures, it is trivial to calculate distance from time.

You are probably better off using a complete module, and looking at the sample code, examples, and the driver software to see how to do this.

Comment: 1) It's worth noting that I'm measuring the distance FROM a particular base station, not distance to some object that I'm pointing the device at and 2) I'm reading the sound in on a mobile device.

Comment: Sound in on a mobile device can't pickup ultrasound.  Inverse square still won't give good results.  You still can't drive an ultrasound transducer with a transformer.

Comment: Probably ought to do a query/response.  The mobile sends a particular sound to the base station, which responds with another particular sound.  The time still tells you the distance, though you do have to account for time lost in the devices.  The results would be more reliable than using the inverse square law on the volume of the signal.

Comment: I have gotten the low end of ultrasound (20khz-22khz) reading on a handful of mobile devices in my own POC, and just as well there are projects that revolve around it: https://github.com/jamrader/XTAudioBeacons. The distance itself doesn't need to be horribly accurate, since I'm using it for a hot-cold system.

Comment: The ping-response idea is definitely very interesting though. The only reason it doesn't work is because I'm not sure I can expect users to have their sound turned on, or for the mobile devices to have a far enough broadcast range.